# invalidate() on custom View does not cause onDraw(Canvas c) to be called

Tags: android, view

For my activity i use 3 custom views stacked.
the lower one is a SurfaceView fullscreen, the middle one is derived from GridView and overrides onDraw to add custom graphic.

The top one is derived directly from View, sits in a corner of the screen and act as a knob to control the others two views (this is the problematic view).

to add a custom animation to this view, i used this pattern:

```
public class StubKnobView extends View{

    private Drawable knob;
    private Point knobPos;
    private float rotation;
    private boolean needsToMove;

    public void moveKnob(){
            /* ...various calculations... */
            this.needsToMove=true;
            invalidate();   //to notify the intention to start animation
    }

    private void updateAnimation(){
        /* ........... */
        this.needsToMove= !animationComplete;
        invalidate();        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int saveCount=canvas.getSaveCount();
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(this.rotation, this.knobPos.x, this.knobPos.y );
        this.knob.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
        if(this.needsToMove){
            updateAnimation();
        }
    }
}
```

ideally, if there is an animation pending, after each drawing cycle the view should auto invalidate.

right now this doesn't work, to force the animation i have to touch the screen to cause a onDraw cycle.
Using "show screen updates" of Dev tools I see that no screen invalidate/update cycle happen , apart when i click the screen.
specifying the dirty rect also ha no effect.

So, any idea where to look to know why this invalidate/draw cycle does not work the way is intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this with a private class in your View.  The idea is not to call `invalidate()` from within `onDraw()`.  Instead, post it on the running queue. Instantiate the private class in your View constructor and then just call `animateKnob.start()` when you want the animation. The `onDraw()` can then just focus on drawing.

```
public void moveKnob(){

  // update the state to draw... KnobPos, rotation
  invalidate()

}


private class AnimateKnob{
   public void start(){
      // Do some calculations if necessary 
      // Start the animation
      MyView.this.post( new Runnable() {
        stepAnimation()
      });
   }

   public void stepAnimation(){
     // update the animation, maybe use an interpolator.
     // Here you could also determine if the animation is complete or not

     MyView.this.moveKnob();

     if( !animationComplete ){
       // Call it again
       MyView.this.post( new Runnable() {
          stepAnimation()
       });
     }

   } 

}
```

Comment: in the end the solution i used was similar to this one

Answer (score 2):

I encontered this situation, and also doubted that `invalidate()` doesn't make `onDraw()` called again.

After simplified the business codes, it's turn out that there is a dead loop - exactly too much iterations, which blocks the UI thread.

So, my advice is that make sure the UI thread going smoothly first.